# Django Template inheritance: how many levels and what page to render

Tags: django, inheritance, django-templates

I would like to have some advice in constructing django template levels.

Reading the docs, I do not understand how to create a template hierarchy structure with more than 2 levels.

For example, I would like to create 3 levels of inheritance:

```
base.html
    └── base_level2.html
            ├── level2_level3_1.html
            └── level2_level3_2.html
```

This is my code:

- base.html

  ```
  First level
  {% block level2 %}{% endblock %}
  ```
- base_level2.html

  ```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block level2 %}
      Second level
      {% block level3_1 %}{% endblock %}
      {% block level3_2 %}{% endblock %}
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- level2_level3_1.html

  ```
  {% extends "base_level2.html" %}
  {% block level3_1 %}
      Third level, part 1
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- level2_level3_2.html

  ```
  {% extends "base_level2.html" %}
  {% block level3_2 %}
      Third level, part 2
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- views.py:

  ```
  def myView(request):
      return render_to_response('level2_level3_1.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

In this way I can see the following on my browser:

```
First level
Second level
Third level, part 1
```

And this is logical to me because I call `render_to response` only on level2_level3_1.html.

Of course, if call level2_level3_2.html, I get the message `Third level, part 2` but not the `Third level, part1`.

How to solve this? Is that a good approach? I've structured stuff in this way because my real templates are very big, a lot of lines of code, so I would like to keep some order.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem? do you want to have `Third level, part 1` and `Third level, part 2`. 
why can't you put both part in the same page? they belong to two different blocks.

Comment: As I said above "I've structured stuff in this way because my real templates are very big...". This is a minimal example but my level2_level3_1.html and level2_level3_2.html are in reality very long and I don't want to merge them in a huge single file.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say if it's a good or bad idea or not without knowing the specific functionality of your templates, but my immediate reaction is that you're trying to over organize your templates.  I think most people would urge you away from more than a 3-tier system because it makes it more difficult to make small changes in the website and more difficult to keep track of where things are.  from the Zen of Python:

> Flat is Better than Nested

The recommendation for a 3-tier system in[Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/) goes like this:

> 1. Each app has a `base_<app_name>.html` template.  App-level base templates share a common parent, base.html.
> 2. Templates within apps share a common parent base_`<app_name>`.html template.
> 3. Any template at the same level as base.html inherits base.html

and for your naming schema, it might look like this:

```
  | Templates/
  |--base.html
  |--someothertemplate.html # extends base.html
  |--level2/
  |----base_level2.html     # extends base.html
  |----level2_1.html        # extends base_level2.html
  |----level2_2.html        # extends base_level3.html
```

EDIT: and there's no real reason for this:

```
    Second level
   {% block level3_1 %}{% endblock %}
   {% block level3_2 %}{% endblock %}
```

where each block refers to the content of one template.  you can simplify that to one block like

```
{% block level3 %}{% endblock level3%}
```

and then in each of the level3 templates, rename the blocks accordingly

Comment: Ok, so no way of split level3, even if it is thousands of lines long?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "split level"? Do those levels show up on the same page? and you're just trying to chop up your page so it's easier to manage?

If your template is thousands of lines long, you're probably doing something wrong.  You should be writing code that generates html for you.

Comment: It is not "split level", But how to split................level3. Yes these levels shows up on the same page, as depicted in the example. Yes, I would like to chop up my page so it's easier to manage. My template is thousands lines long because its very huge and complicated, not because I do non use Django facilities, template tags and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the best way of doing it but you might user `include` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include

something like this for `base_level2.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block level2 %}
Second level
{% include "level2_level3_1.html" %}   
{% include "level2_level3_2.html" %} 
{% endblock %}
```

i've not tested this, so not sure it works.

and btw:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process.

Comment: Yes, it's for that clause that I didn't used the include tag.

Comment: but it should do what you need, you can even pass parameters.