# Tree in generic template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am new with Django but I understand that the aim is to never reinvent the wheel. I am developing an application to supervise a factory and in all the html file I need to implement a tree representing the structure of the factory.

-> Factory

-> Production Area

-> Machine 1

-> Machine 2

etc

So I decided to put this tree structure in the base.html file and extend it on every others html files.

The problem is that I need to extract the element from my database, using the views.py files in order to call the render function to send it to the html file.

My question is how to access this data in the base.html, because he dont got any views.py to use a render function.

Thanks, Baptiste.

Comment: I don't understand? Do you want to put a tree in all the views (python functions, your application logic) or in all templates (HTML files, the visible part for the end user) ?

Comment: In the base.html templates which is extended in all the others html file, I need to call a function render, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This is far too vague. What is the "tree" here? How are you outputting it?

Comment: I tried to edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to show up in every template of your website (a tree in your case), you can put it in a base template and [inherit from that template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

I personally (and many others as well) use a 3-level template structure. You can find an example/explanation in [this GitHub repo](https://gist.github.com/monokrome/5447258) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16900872/9225671). Feel free to adapt the idea to your needs.

So in your case you could put your tree structure (the factory structure/layout) in your base template. If the data of the tree has to be fetched from the database, then you could use a [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) so that you don't have to repeat the tree-fetching-code in every view.

Comment: Thank you is exactly what I was looking for.