# Django template's "extends" tag does not work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I also checked the similar questions here but my problem is not one of them. Actually I am not getting a specific error but getting anything literally.

I have a main template called **dashboard.html** and it is in the project level template folder. I have a block in it like this;

```
*** some code here ***

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'products:test' %}">
       <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
       Products
    </a>
</li>

*** some code here

{% block test_html %}
{% endblock test_html %}
```

I have an application called "products" and in its template folder, I have **test.html** file. Here its content;

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block test_html %}
  <h1>test</h1>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <h1>test</h1>
{% endblock test_html %}
```

My **products/base.html** file;

```
{% extends 'dashboard.html' %}
```

My **products/urls.py** file;

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='products/test.html'), name='test'),
]
```

When I load the page, nothing happens. Here is also the screen shot link;

http://i.prntscr.com/wtGNfcj4RZOClPndNfnX3w.png

I am expecting `h1` tags from my test.html file on that blank area shown on the screen shot.

PS: Actually I am expecting to show `IndexView` from my urls.py but for testing purposes I created a test.html to check whether it works with a simple html.

Thank you for time and answers.

**EDIT:** If I change `{% extends 'dashboard.html' %}` to `{% extends 'base.html' %}` in **products/base.html** file which is also in my project level template directory, then products' page is working. What I do not understand is that can two different applications not use the same `html` file which is in the project level template directory? Is there a rule like that?

Comment: Does your products/base.html really just contain a single line?

Comment: Yes. Actually I have another app called "accounts" and its base.html also contains same code line (only 1 line) and its template is working. I don't understand why it is not working for "products" app.

Answer (score 0):

Template inheritance doesn't work like that. A child template can only populate blocks that are defined in the immediate parent; so the parent can't be empty. You need to define the (empty) `test_html` block in products/base.html as well.

Comment: I added `{% block test_html %}{% endblock test_html %}` to my products/base.html file after `extends`tag but there is still no change.

Comment: Why did you do that, instead of `block test_html`?

Comment: I think I am implementing this rule here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899917/django-template-inheritance-how-many-levels-and-what-page-to-render . Do you have any idea why it is not working, @Daniel Roseman?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem occurs because of the css. My product html was overwritten by dashboard's container.